# PHP | Добавить массив в конец другого массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива:

```
$arrayP = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

и

```
$arrayN = array(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5);
```

Как создать массив $arrayPN(Добавить в конец массива $arrayP элементы $arrayN)?
Должно получиться  1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5 в $arrayPN

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php
У вас странный синтаксис `&arrayP` имелось в виду `$arrayP`?

Comment: array_merge как-то криво объединяет, у меня ни одного отрицательного числа в массива в итоге.

Answer (score 10):

array_merge работает отлично

```
$arrayP = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arrayN = array(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_merge($arrayP, $arrayN));
echo '</pre>';
```

результат:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => -1
        [6] => -2
        [7] => -3
        [8] => -4
        [9] => -5
    )
```

Answer (score -3):

Может немного громоздко, но все же:
Проходим циклом по всем элементам нужного нам массива, и при помощи array_push добавляем каждый из этих элементов в указанный массив.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayP); $i++)
 {
    array_push($array, $arrayP[$i]); 
 }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.